# curl callback function threading

Tags: c++, c, curl, callback

I have done some googling but haven't found the answer to this as of yet.

When you registrar a function with curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function) is that function guaranteed to be completed before curl_easy_perform(curl) returns? Or is it possible that function is being ran in parallel and may still be running when the easy_perform returns?

Comment: In fact, the writefunction does finish before the call to curl_easy_perform() is completed. You can expect to have all the info in there by the time the call is done (if you have successfully downloaded the page/file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have an empirical source file+line number to quote to support this, having used libcurl quite a number of times in various projects over the years, I can confidently say: yes, curl_easy_perform will block until the write function you supply is finished being invoked.

Comment: I've used C++ future and curl thread ended before saving the file. The file is created but is empty.

Comment: @b26 : A future is a synchronization mechanism so I don't see what that has to do with anything.

Comment: an std future returns once a result is ready (return of curl response). 
I have a list of files to download using libcurl, I have the callback set and all.
The thread returns before finishing writing the last file, so it seems the callback is not called in the last downloaded file.

Comment: @b26 : If data isn't ready when the future is finished then you're using the future wrong. I have no idea what that has to do with this question/answer. You should consider posting a question *with code* to diagnose your actual problem.

Comment: The question above is about the callback being called or not. I gave an example where it's not called. There are no guarantees it will be called zero, one or multiple times especially when using threads with future abstraction. You claimed the opposite but haven't posted any facts about it.

Comment: @b26 : No, you did not give an example; you vaguely described an instance where you had problems, but didn't show any code whatsoever; all signs point to the actual issue being with your synchronization code, not with anything being described in this question/answer. Please stop polluting the comments here unless you have code to link and reference.